# Select whole line but cursor in the left in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code there is `expandLineSelection` command in keyboard shortcuts to select a whole line, and  after trigger this, the cursor is in the next line,

[image]

Is there any way to select the whole line but the cursor is at the left most of the line?

Comment: Doesn't this mean that it has selected the whole line + the line feed character(s)? I think by convention the cursor is always placed *after* the selection.

Comment: Do you want the newline selected? So that cutting removes the line and does not leave a blank line in its place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extensions [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Define a keybinding:

```json
{
    "key": "alt+k",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "expandLineSelection",
            "selectby.swapActive"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can use the same keyboard shortcut as defined for `expandLineSelection`

Answer (score 0):

Go to beginning of next line (<kbd>Home</kbd>) and hit

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>  (select the preceding newline)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>  (select to the beginning)

If you really want it in one command, use the multi-command extension.