# How to simultaneously select a copied line in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, clion

I can copy an entire line under cursor using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut. Is it possible to also select this line to visually hint that the line was copied (and also to give the opportunity to remove or edit the line instantly)? That's how it works in CLion, but VSCode just silently copies the line (by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to remove the line if nothing selected.

to select and copy line if nothing selected create a keybinding

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+c",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "expandLineSelection",
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
}
```

---

A different selection, but first the copy command:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+c",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "cursorLineEnd",
      "cursorLineStartSelect"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There is one problem though. When using this keybinding my cursor moves to the next line and the full line (including a newline character) is selected. Is it possible to preserve the cursor position?

Comment: Oh, I see, nvm. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67899863/20031500

Comment: if you have a selection one of the edges of the selection is the cursor, not even CLion has the cursor somewhere inside the selection, if you want only decoration you need to write an extension, your question was to also select the copied line @cppbest

Comment: This would be improved with the `cursorLineEnd` and `cursorLineStartSelect` commands instead of `expandLineSelection`.

Comment: @Mark I added an alternative using these commands

Comment: Where can I find the reference for all possible commands? I can't find the docs for `cursorLineStartSelect`, for example.

Comment: @cppbest the key bind (Keyboard Shortcuts) GUI has all the commands